# Changing label fonts in R plots

Tags: r

I encountered a very annoying problem. I need to do plots of time series, but cannot change the font in the y axis label to bold. I have figured out (with some help here) how to control everything else.
I am enclosing the "plot" part of the code, a time series example, and the plot I get.
Thanks in advance for your help.
G

```
dev.new(width=9, height=5, unit="in")

par(mgp=c(1.5,1,0),font.lab=2)

plot(TimeseriesM.ts,axes=FALSE, xlim=c(1997,2019), ylim=c(.05,0.35), 
  type="b", pch=20, lwd=1.5, ylab=expression('[Chl] mg m'^-3),
  xlab="Date",cex.lab=3, family= "serif", font.lab=2)

title("IOSTZ", family="serif", font=2, line=-2, adj= .05)

axis(2, pos=1997, at=yticks, labels=sprintf("%.2f", yticks), family="serif",font.axis=2) 

axis(1, pos=0.05, at= xticks, labels = xticks, tck= -.01, family="serif",font.axis=2) 

xticks <- seq(1997,2019,1)

yticks <- seq(0.05,0.35,0.05)

lines(lowess(time(TimeseriesM.ts),TimeseriesM.ts), lwd=3, col="grey")
```

Here is a snippet of the data (TimeseriesM.ts).

> ```
> Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul
> 1997                                                                      
> 1998 0.1736600 0.1652400 0.1777900 0.1955000 0.2069500 0.2100500 0.2109000
> 1999 0.1657000 0.1607000 0.1658000 0.1829800 0.2146300 0.2158300 0.2042000
> 2000 0.1731400 0.1534500 0.1618500 0.1813400 0.2011800 0.2067400 0.2052600
> ```

[This is the time series. Note the y axis label.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFKTC.png)

Answer (score 0):

install [extrafont](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extrafont/extrafont.pdf) library for fonts..

Working example:

```
library(extrafont)
font_import()
loadfonts(device="win")       #Register fonts for Windows bitmap output
fonts()                       #vector of font family names

library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +     
ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
theme_bw() +
theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", face="bold", size=12)) #Times New Roman, 12pt, Bold
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks for the suggestion.  I do not see why I would need the extrafont since I am not trying to do pdf or postscript output.  In any case, I can bold everything but the y axis, so the issue must be elsewhere.   In any case, for some reason, font_import is failing in my system. Something to figure out later.